# Regex not working in java

Tags: java, regex

I have this regex `[a-zA-Z]\d\d\\$\d\d-\d\d\d\d` and my value is `A11$12-9190`. But it is not matching. Any clues?

Comment: That regex is not valid.

Comment: What's the actual Java string you're using?

Comment: You are escaping \ before the $ thus reaching the end of the string yet you are searching for more digits afterwards. Not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each backslash `\` have to be escaped by an extra backslash, `\\`, in java patterns. Note that your backslash in front of the dollar sign is already escaped.

The resulting regex would be:

```
[a-zA-Z]\\d\\d\\$\\d\\d-\\d\\d\\d\\d
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically what's happening is that Java assumes your \d is an escape character for the String, you'll need to transform it into \\d - the first \ to escape the second \ that escapes the d for the regex!

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is not valid.  e.g.,

```
  String test = "A11$12-9190";
  String regex = "[a-zA-Z]\\d\\d\\$\\d\\d-\\d\\d\\d\\d";

  System.out.println(test.matches(regex));
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you escaping all the `\`? If you have a string, you'll have to do `"\\d"`.